# Angular Reactive form builder, can we set the form control value type?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formbuilder

Can we have typed reactive forms using Angular formbuilder? What I mean is setting the TValue on the formcontrol so we get the right type. E.g.

```
public myForm= this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(142)]])
  });
```

If I want to apply it as a string to a variable. It does not work, as it can be null and undefined.

```
let name: string = this.myForm.get("name")?.value; // Not working!
```

With the "normal" FormControls I can tell it it's TValue type.

```
nameFormControl = new FormControl<string>('', {nonNullable: true});
```

Direct initialization is then possible:

```
let name: string= this.nameFormControl.value; // works
```

Can we have the same type safety in form builders?

Comment: You can use `this.fb.nonNullable.group({...})`., see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#formbuilder-and-nonnullableformbuilder) or, e.g. `form=this.fb.group({prop1:this.fb.control<string>('')})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you can set easily `non-nullable` type in `FormBuilder`. It's even more strict to typed `FormControl` (cannot be `null` by default).
Example:

```
    formBuilder.nonNullable.control<Type>(...);
```

`group` and `array` works either.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can assign form control

```
public myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required, 
      Validators.maxLength(142)
    ])
  });
```

then you can access:

```
let name: string = this.myForm.get("name")?.value;
```

Here is stackblitz for reference: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cpjcmm)

Comment: shouldn't it be `new FormControl<string>('', [
          Validators.required, 
          Validators.maxLength(142)
        ])`

Comment: if setting a empty string so it will implicit set the type to string

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This would still not work, as it can be undefined or null. But I get it now.